# How to use "." in LWC datatable in a column of type number?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, number, column

I noticed that is not possible to use a number like "12.6" in a cell of type "number" but is only accepted a number like "12,6".
How can I allow the use of the "dot" character?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Have you checked that this is not dependent on the locale setting of the current user? I expect it to work if the locale is set to US

Comment: Your user locale will determine the thousands separator and decimal separator. Try using a locale that uses full-stop (`.`) for the decimal separator.

Comment: I want to use both "." and ","

Comment: Or, if it is possible, when a user type "." I want to dinamically change "." to ","

Comment: @LucaDaneluzzo tip: tag the users that commented your post so that they can see your response

Comment: @sfdcfox please see my comment above.
Thanks,Luca

Comment: @LucaDaneluzzo You can't allow the use of both, because it would create problems. `1,200` and `1.200` can both mean either one-and-two-fifths, or one-thousand-two-hundred. To fix this problem, your locale is used to determine the format of the number. The user's locale determines which separator to use.